# Minima selection in collection according to a partial ordering

Tags: scala, partial-ordering

unfortunately I am forced to post the minimal amount of code snippets I can, so I will do my best to clearly explain the problem, apologies in advance for the verbosity.

**Problem statement (design):**

I have an abstract class Predicate which is implemented by two subclasses  NumericPredicate and CategoricalPredicate, which are equipped with a "predicate type" and a "comparison value":

NumericPredicate -> type is "<=" or ">", and the comparison value is of type double (but any comparable object would do)
CategoricalPredicate -> type is "is-in" or "is-not-in", and the comparison value is a set of strings (but any unordered type equipped with equality would work here)

This predicates forms the head of a rule (an ordered sequence of type Predicate), which matches if all the predicates hold.

In this context, a predicate can be "redundant" (e.g., "value <= 2" is more specific than "value <= 3", so the latter can be safely removed) and can be removed to improve the readability of the rules (and secondarily also have a performance gain, but that is not the main point here).

**Goal:**

I am now implementing the "reduction" phase for such rule heads, and I am looking for a clean way to achieve this. In practice, given a partial ordering over the element of the collection (partial because predicates of different kind cannot be compared), my reduction consists in the minima  (one per predicate type) among the predicates of the original collections.

**My actual solution:**

I have equipped Predicate class with the trait Comparable ("with Comparable[Predicate]"), and the method "compareTo" is therefore implemented in NumericPredicate and CategoricalPredicate:

In what follows the implementation of the method for the NumericPredicate class:

```
override def compareTo(o: Predicate) = {

  if(this.getPredicateType != o.getPredicateType)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Predicates of different type cannot be compared: " +
    this.getPredicateType + " vs " + o.getPredicateType)

  val num: NumericPredicate = o.asInstanceOf[NumericPredicate]

  if(this.threshold == num.threshold)
    0
  else {
    if(isMinEq == (this.threshold < num.threshold)) -1 else 1
  }
}
```

Now, what I want is achieved by organizing the different predicates into comparable sub collections, that are processed independently, as follows:

```
 def simplify(steps: Array[Predicate]): Array[Predicate] ={
    val groups =
      filters.map(p => (p.getPredicateType, s))
      .groupBy(_._1)

    groups.map(_._2.min).map(_._2).toArray   
}
```

**Questions:**

1. is there a more idiomatic way to implement a partial ordering in Scala (and being able to keep all the minima among incomparable kinds)? 
   EDIT: I am aware I am trying to "hack" a partial ordering into a total ordering (as it should be for Comparable), but I fail to see how I can achieve what I want through the more appropriate trait PartialOrdering
2. assuming that my design choice is ok, would it be better to return 0 or throw an exception when two incomparable objects are compared? (I have the impression that I am silently suppressing an error, because in this context it is wrong an meaningless to compare two incomparable elements)

Comment: I would start by questioning the design. Applying a general comparison to a trait or abstract class seems to put you into a pickle, since partial ordering is something rarely desirable when reasoning about a program. Why not let each predicate implement it's own comparison algorithm, where the types are forced to be the same?

Comment: I have the same feeling somehow, but how would you then implement the "simplify" method? Would you filter by predicate class and predicate type first and then apply the comparison?

Comment: You would group by each type and apply comparisons only between similar types. Perhaps using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572195/scala-filtering-based-on-type

Comment: What I don't really like about that is that if I add many more predicate types I will end up with changing the code all the time to accomodate them (as the comparison method will be class specific, not at Predicate class level, if I got it right). Did I miss something?

Comment: You're right, you'd pay the extra work of applying a predicate to each type you add, but you get to keep *type safety*, especially if multiple developers are going to be creating such comparisons. Also one thing to consider is how your code will look when this expands, making the `Predicate` comparison difficult to reason about and extend. But if you have similar comparison methods, you can reuse the comparing. As a side note, if in Scala, use the `Ordered[T]` trait instead of Java comparison.

Comment: I see the advantages of your suggestion, but I still hope in a solution design that could provide a "global" solution. +1 for the Ordered[T] trait, coming from Java I have always similar issues, thanks!